# gRPC Concurrency for Stubs

Tags: java, concurrency, microservices, grpc, grpc-java

In gRPC I would like some more information on the way the server handles requests.

Are requests executed in parallel? Or does the server spawn a new thread for each request, and execute them in parallel? Is there a way to modify this behavior? I understand that in client-streaming rpc's that message order is guaranteed.

- If I send Request A followed by Request B to the same RPC, is it guaranteed that A will be executed first before B begins processing? Or are they each their own thread and executed in parallel with no guarantee that A finishes before B.

Ideally I would like to send a request to the server, the server acknowledges receipt of the request, and then the request is added to a queue to be processed sequentially, and returns a response once it's been processed. An approach I was exploring is to use an external task queue (like RabbitMQ) to queue the work done by the service but I want to know if there is a better approach.

Also -- on a somewhat related note -- does gRPC have a native retry counter mechanism? I have a particularly error-prone RPC that may have to retry up to 3 times (with an arbitrary delay between retries) before it is successful. This is something that could be implemented with RabbitMQ as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grpc-java passes RPCs to the service using the `Executor` provided by `ServerBuilder.executor(Executor)`, or a [cached thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--) if no executor is provided.

There is no ordering between simultaneous RPCs. RPCs can arrive in any order.

You could use a server-streaming RPC to allow the server to respond twice, once for acknowledgement and once for completion. You can use a `oneof` in the response message to allow sending the two different responses.

grpc-java as experimental retry support. [gRFC A6](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A6-client-retries.md) describes the support. The configuration is delivered to the client via service config. Retries are disabled by default, so overall you would want something like `channelBuilder.defaultServiceConfig(serviceConfig).enableRetry()`. You can also reference the [hedging example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples#Basic-examples) which is very similar to retries.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to natively set a RPC as synchronous? Meaning that the server will only execute one at a time and have the rest wait? I could use some kind of locking at the service implementation.

Comment: No, you can't make one RPC wait for another. You can use a single thread for the `executor()`, but that would only serialize callbacks and each RPC has multiple callbacks so there is still ability of reordering. But even if such a thing existed, there is nothing that would require that your preferred RPC would be received first. You should be able to use locking even if multiple RPCs are allowed concurrently.

Comment: So, for example in Java using proto and GRPC, the recommended approach is to have a lock in the implementation of the generated "ImplBase" classes? Just want to confirm.

Comment: I wouldn't say "recommended," as there are many possible solutions and they vary in complexity and suitability based on your service. But yes, using a lock in the class extending the generated ImplBase would be fine.